# openssl command in php

Tags: php, openssl, x509certificate

I want to generate `example.com.crt` and `example.com.pem` using php. The Linux command to get the files is given:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -x509 -days 3652 -nodes 
            -out example.com.crt -keyout example.com.pem
```

I want to get the two file contents in two string in php. What is the php equivalent code for this?

UPDATE: Please don't ask to execute the Linux command.

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: @PrashantPokhriyal, I don't even remember what happened yesterday :)

Answer (score 2):

here another command:

```
<?php 
// generate 2048-bit RSA key
$pkGenerate = openssl_pkey_new(array(
    'private_key_bits' => 2048,
    'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA
));

// get the private key
openssl_pkey_export($pkGenerate,$pkGeneratePrivate); // NOTE: second argument is passed by reference

// get the public key
$pkGenerateDetails = openssl_pkey_get_details($pkGenerate);
$pkGeneratePublic = $pkGenerateDetails['key'];

// free resources
openssl_pkey_free($pkGenerate);

// fetch/import public key from PEM formatted string
// remember $pkGeneratePrivate now is PEM formatted...
// this is an alternative method from the public retrieval in previous
$pkImport = openssl_pkey_get_private($pkGeneratePrivate); // import
$pkImportDetails = openssl_pkey_get_details($pkImport); // same as getting the public key in previous
$pkImportPublic = $pkImportDetails['key'];
openssl_pkey_free($pkImport); // clean up

// let's see 'em
echo "\n".$pkGeneratePrivate
    ."\n".$pkGeneratePublic
    ."\n".$pkImportPublic
    ."\n".'Public keys are '.(strcmp($pkGeneratePublic,$pkImportPublic)?'different':'identical').'.';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [phpseclib, a pure PHP X.509 implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net):

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/x509/examples.html#selfsigned

```
<?php
include('File/X509.php');
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

// create private key / x.509 cert for stunnel / website
$privKey = new Crypt_RSA();
extract($privKey->createKey());
$privKey->loadKey($privatekey);

$pubKey = new Crypt_RSA();
$pubKey->loadKey($publickey);
$pubKey->setPublicKey();

$subject = new File_X509();
$subject->setDNProp('id-at-organizationName', 'phpseclib demo cert');
//$subject->removeDNProp('id-at-organizationName');
$subject->setPublicKey($pubKey);

$issuer = new File_X509();
$issuer->setPrivateKey($privKey);
$issuer->setDN($subject->getDN());

$x509 = new File_X509();
//$x509->setStartDate('-1 month'); // default: now
//$x509->setEndDate('+1 year'); // default: +1 year

$result = $x509->sign($issuer, $subject);
echo "the stunnel.pem contents are as follows:\r\n\r\n";
echo $privKey->getPrivateKey();
echo "\r\n";
echo $x509->saveX509($result);
echo "\r\n";
?>
```

That'll create a private key and a self-signed X.509 cert (as your CLI example does) with the private keys corresponding public key.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the command with the [exec()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) or [system()](http://www.php.net/system) function, then read the output files with [file_get_contents()](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents).

Comment: `exec` not allowed on hostings.

Answer (score 0):

There is OpenSSL extension to PHP, you  should check if it is not enough for you as it would be better to use it insteaf of `exec()`:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php

Comment: I saw that. But I couldn't find how to use it.

Comment: if it is enabled you use it as any other PHP method/function - see docs I linked to

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps it's not the finest solution, but you can use exec() and file_get_contents(), something like:

```
exec("openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -x509 -days 3652 -nodes -out example.com.crt -keyout example.com.pem");
$crtFile = file_get_contents("example.com.crt");
$pemFile = file_get_contents("example.com.pem");
```

Be aware file permissions and obviously file paths. Better if you add some error handling around these commands.

Read more: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

And: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: `EXEC` not allowed on shared hostings.