# how to interpret openssl command line tool with a php function

Tags: php, openssl

I am having problems with calling openssl command line tool from the php script and in my current situation I would much prefer to use some kind of php function instead.
Can anybody please point me to such a function if it exists.

Comment: You say you have having problems, so what have you tried.  Post the code that is not working and I'm sure someone will be able to help find your problem.

Comment: I guess it depends what you're wanting to achieve, but perhaps this topic covers it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13622630/openssl-command-in-php